# How to combine scales for colour and size into one legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how to colorize the size_scale in `scale_size() {ggplot2}` in a plot where the size and color are from the same data.

Example:

```
 library(ggplot2)
    df<-as.data.frame(cbind(rep(1:10,10),
                            rep(1:10,each=10),
                            rnorm(100)))

    ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+
      geom_point(aes(colour=V3,size=V3))+
      scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="black")+
      scale_size(range=c(1,10))
```

As you can see the `V3` is the same for the color and the size of the data points. How can I merge the color gradient to the size scale (except do this manually in program such as Illustrator...)? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `guides()` function of `ggplot2`. In this case:

```
ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=V3,size=V3))+
  scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="black")+
  scale_size(range=c(1,10)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(), size = guide_legend())
```

ggplot2 will try to integrate the scales for you. It doesn't in this case because the default guide for a color scale is a colorbar and the default guide for size is a normal legend. Once you set them both to be legends, ggplot 2 takes over and combines them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by requesting to use not a `colourbar` but a legend for the colour. Using your data frame:

```
  ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+
     geom_point(aes(colour=V3,size=V3))+
     scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="black",guide="legend")+
     scale_size(range=c(1,10))
```

If you also want the colour bar, there is a little hack to achieve this that profits from the fact that you are not using the aesthetic `fill`. So you can map `V3` to `fill` as well and it will draw a colourbar for this scale:

```
  ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+
     geom_point(aes(colour=V3,size=V3,fill=V3))+
     scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="black",guide="legend")+
     scale_size(range=c(1,10)) + 
     scale_fill_gradient(low="grey",high="black") +
     guides(fill=guide_colourbar(reverse=TRUE))
```

I added the call to `guides` in order to have the colours in the colourbar ordered the same way as in the legend for the sizes.

[image]