# Generating a fancy dotplot with R

Tags: r, ggplot2

i really like the dotplot function in clusterprofiler package. For some reasons related to the object this program creates by itself i cannot replicate this graph with my data.

So my question is, could someone point me to a similar dotplot package/function for achieving the same plot? 
Its important to me to show that some of these "biological processes" are present in some clusters (x-axis) ad not in other, and that the colour of the dot is representing its importance (fold). The size of the dot would be represented by an integer.

here the data example i want to show.
thanks in advance.

```
biological process  cluster1-fold   cluster2-fold   cluster3-fold   cluster1-num    cluster2-num    cluster3-num
cell cycle  0   3   5   0   23  24
dna replication 4   2   0   43  22  0
```

[here the plot i want to replicate](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1237&bih=643&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CnuJWr__C5GjwAL75begCg&q=dot%20plot%20clusterprofiler&oq=dot%20plot%20clusterprofiler&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1075724.1078823.0.1078885.16.12.0.4.4.0.121.1038.8j3.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.9.464...0j0i8i30k1j0i30k1j0i13k1.0.qwggEnQuFKc#imgdii=oc4x-_2wBWNp5M:&imgrc=jxIBs0SCX7CUkM:)

Comment: the plot you are pointing to has most likely been produced with ggplot2, so the tagging of your question is not far. ggplot2 needs long data, so your data how you present it is not really in a good structure for it. Also, you present the data in a way that is not very useful for us to help you. What is the structure of the data? Is this a list? A data frame?

Comment: Maybe the question and answers [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060000/how-to-combine-scales-for-colour-and-size-into-one-legend) could help you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my data is a dataframe.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. thanks @nadizan